# react fullcalendar v6 - add dropdown

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

Hello I'm struggling to add custom dropdown which will contain day/week/month option instead of standard buttons. Cannot find any source how to achieve it. Docs say only about custom buttons but they won't help in this case.

```
const getHeaderProps = () => ({
    left: 'createTask',
    center: 'today prev,next dayGridMonth',
    right: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGridDay prev,next',
  });

<FullCalendar
        plugins={[dayGridPlugin]}
        initialView="dayGridMonth"
        headerToolbar={getHeaderProps()}
        editable
        eventClick={handleEventClick}
        weekends
        events={events}
        eventContent={CustomEventContent}
        customButtons={{
          createTask: {
            text: 'Create Task',
            click: handleTaskDialogOpen,
          },
        }}
      />
```

Comment: There is no support for this in the fullCalendar API currently. Either you have to inject the HTML yourself in the right place, or you can just place such controls outside the calendar area.